# How to open a custom DLL file/class from another solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

How can I open a DLL class/file that I created from another project/solution?

For example: I have a class "AClass" in a DLL that I'm referencing. When debugging a project, I'm able to put a breakpoint in my project and then step into the DLL's classes and view variables and insert breakpoints. However, it would take me a while to reach the class (AClass) that I actually want via stepping through the code. Is there a way to open the AClass file in the solution and insert breakpoints from there, instead of having to step through classes to reach it?

I have been unable to find where I can do this, but it seems possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The recommended way is to add the DLL project into your solution. Projects are designed to be used in multiple solutions.

Once the DLL project is in the solution, you can add a 'project reference' to it in the main project.

This way you can set breakpoints in the DLL project from the referencing solution.

Comment: What if you have access to the source but not the project (Like the .NET framework source stepping option in Visual Studio)?

Comment: I don't think you can open files that aren't in the solution. If you have the source you could always create a project and use that. Another idea, you might be able to open the file by Go to definition on the desired class, though I don't know how much functionality that allows you.